# When Published in MS Teams Channel, the Chat Bot Name is getting included in the user utterance thus providing incorrect utterance to LUIS

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDc4R.jpg) we are  facing an issue while developing  a chat bot using Microsoft Botframework V4 hosted on Azure. The  Chat has issues when published in a MS Teams Channel but, the same Chatbot works fine on MS Teams Private Chat  and even Web Chat i.e. All pointing to the same Microsoft APP ID on Azure.

### From Within MS Teams Channel:

The ChatBot gets an incorrect User utterance when user chats to ChatBot from within a MS Teams Channel.

#### Bug:###

   As visible in the screenshot,  User types “hi” and the Chat Bot returns the text “VA Check ID Bothi” from the Chat Step Context (stepContext.Context.Activity.Text) . This is incorrect as, the Bot Name "VA Check ID Bot" is getting included in the user utterance.
•   Therefore the Incorrect Intent is getting recognized by LUIS i.e. the “Help” Intent.

*  A simple echo Bot also has the same issue when published in a Teams Channel, but work fine in a MS Teams Private Chat.*

### From Within Teams Private Chat

o   The Chat Bot gets a correct User utterance, when user chats to the same chat bot from within a private chat on MS Teams.
o   As you can see in the screen shot,the User types “hi” and the Chat Bot returns the same text “hi” from the Chat Step Context (stepContext.Context.Activity.Text). This is correct.

   Therefore the correct Intent is getting recognized by LUIS i.e. the “Greeting” Intent.

Since its the same chatbot with the same MS APP ID hosted on MS Azure, the Chatbot should behave the same when used from within MS Teams Private Chat or MS teams Channel.

The Chatbot also works perfectly fine in Web Chat on Azure Portal

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is the working behavior for a long time in Microsoft Teams.

What we did was adding a MicrosoftTeamsMiddleware that basically checks the `activity.ChannelId` and if it is `msteams` replace the bot name in the `activity.Text`.

You can access the activity since the middleware receives the ITurnContext. Modifications to this activity are seen by the rest of the pipeline so everything works smoothly and the rest of the bot is unaware of this problem.

I recommend that you inspect/log the activity text because in our case it would be something like `<at>Bot Name</at>`. So you need to replace all of that with an empty string.

If you also use a middleware for querying LUIS, make sure this new middleware is registered before the LUIS middleware so that the activity.Text is fine before the LUIS middleware acts.

Comment: The fix did not work, Luis continues to send the incorrect Intent even though we are successfully replacing the bot name in the user uttrance :  public class TeamsUttranceObserver : IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
        {           
            if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.Equals("msteams")) turnContext.Activity.Text = turnContext.Activity.Text.Replace("RPA Chat Bot", "");
        }
    }

Comment: the solution provided by Andre did the job partially where It removed the Bot name from the utterance but, somehow <> </> remained in the text. Therefore, I had to add utterances  LUIS which included the angular brackets

Answer (score 0):

You could use a middleware like Andre suggested, but I just straight up did a regex replace on activity.text for every activity. You are going to see the  tags from teams, but I also covered @ just in case. Here are the scenarios I covered:

- Mention starts with @ or `<at>` (and optional check for trailing `</at>`)
- Mention uses bot short name (e.g. YourBot)
- Mention uses bot long name (e.g. Your Bot Long Name)
- Mention *may* be followed by a space (it's possible it will not be)

Here is my code. I am using nodejs and this bot used an older 4.3 template for core_bot but similar method should work for C# and other SDK versions.

```js
async onTurn(context) {
    if (context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        context._activity.text = context._activity.text.replace(/(@|<at>)((YourBot)|(Your Bot Long Name))(<\/at>)? ?/g, '');

        const results = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(context);
```

That covers all the scenarios above. Since I do this at the beginning of the turn before I call the LUIS recognizer and/or QnA Maker, the text sent to those services does not contain the mention.

Comment: I changed the stepContext.Context.Activity.Text = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text.Replace("RPA Chat Bot", "")  but, LUIS is somehow still returning the incorrect intent... Does it mean that , just replacing "stepContext.Context.Activity.Text" isn't working and that, we have to replace the value of some other attribute in the Context object?  Am attaching the screen shot tof the code..

Comment: Can you check in LUIS with utterance of "hi" and see what is returned? Confidence on the intent in your screenshot is very low, so it's possible that is the highest score intent. To deal with low confidence intents, I'm replacing the topIntent with 'None' if the confidence is below 0.5. You do this right after the recognizer result is returned and before you switch case on the topIntent (or however you are acting on the intent information from the result).

Comment: the solution provided by Andre did the job partially where It removed the Bot name from the utterance but, somehow <> </> remained in the text. Therefore, I had to add utterances  LUIS which included the angular brackets

Comment: The regex I mentioned above does take care of the brackets if you want to give it a try.